# How to handle a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm quite new to Java and stuck with handling NullPointerException -

I have a method as follows in order to build a HTTP Request as follows -

```
``
 public static Http.Request Requester(String pingpoint) {
        final String endPoint = URLBuilder.constructPing(pingpoint);
        return BackendHttpRequest
                .GET()
                .pingURL(endPoint)
                .build();
    }
``
```

I don't want users to provide -

1. "~" - A tilde as an input
2. null - No null input

If user provides either of the above inputs we need to handle them as a NullPointerException.

What I'm trying to do -

```
`` 
public static Http.Request Requester(String pingpoint) {

try {
 if(pingpoint != && pingpoint.equals("~")) {
           final String endPoint = URLBuilder.constructPing(pingpoint);
        return BackendHttpRequest
                .GET()
                .pingURL(endPoint)
                .build();
}
} catch(NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("NullPointerException thrown!");
        }
}

``
```

However, Intellij is point to an error at the very end of curly braces to return a value of HTTP Request. I'm not sure what to return.

Any teachings on this will be really helpful! Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Java you define your return type in the method signature...so `public static Http.Request` states you have a public method returning an `Http.Request` thus this the the object type you must return

Comment: What does "handle them as a NullPointerException" mean?

Comment: I want to throw an error message saying "The pingpoint entered is not correct"

Comment: Before posting here, read *The Java Tutorials* by Oracle, free-of-cost. See [*How to Throw Exceptions*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html).

Answer (score 0):

probably you want to throw exception, like this:

```
public static Http.Request Requester(String pingpoint) {
  if (pingpoint == null || pingpoint.equals("~"))
    throw new NullPointerException();

  final String endPoint = URLBuilder.constructPing(pingpoint);
  return BackendHttpRequest.GET().pingURL(endPoint).build();
}
```

Comment: How can we throw an error message to this? Saying "The pingpoint entered is not correct"

Comment: @newwbie `throw new NullPointerException("The pingpoint entered is not correct");`

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to write a JUnit test to perform assertEquals("The pingpoint entered is not correct", actual) . However both are not coming true. The actual is coming out as follows-  java.lang.NullPointerException: The pingpoint entered is not correct

Comment: @newwbie: it evaluates to false because you're comparing the expected message string to the exception object. Instead you should compare the expected message to the message in the exception (call getMessage())